# How to build an iterator to get all possible combinations in a list

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate the variance of a stock portfolio. In order to achieve this, I need to calculate the weighted covariances between the assets. I have a class including a field to store the weight of each asset in the portfolio and a field to store the list of calculated stock returns. So far I have built a helper function to traverse the list of assets and perform one part of the calculation using the apache.commons.math3 library (please see code below). However, this is clearly wrong because he does not include all possible combinations of the assets. I have looked into the apache.commons combinationsIterator, but I am not sure how to implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private double getPortfolioVariance(double portfolioVariance, List<AssetDto> assets, int historyLength) {
    for (int i = 0; i < assets.size() - 1; i++) {
        double weight = assets.get(i).getWeight() / 100;
        double weightOther = assets.get(i + 1).getWeight() / 100;
        if (assets.get(i).getStockReturns() != null && assets.get(i + 1) != null) {
            List<Double> returns = assets.get(i).getStockReturns().stream().limit(historyLength).collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<Double> returnsOther = assets.get(i).getStockReturns().stream().limit(historyLength).collect(Collectors.toList());
            Covariance covariance = new Covariance();
            double assetsCovariance = covariance.
                    covariance(returns.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray(),
                            returnsOther.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray());
            portfolioVariance += 2 * weight * weightOther * assetsCovariance;
        }
    }
    return portfolioVariance;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *CombinatoricsUtils* class from [commons-math3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3) project. The utility method *combinationsIterator* creates an iterator, which produces all the combinations of n to k without repetitions. The example below:

```
private double getPortfolioVariance(double portfolioVariance, List<AssetDto> assets, int historyLength) {
    Iterator<int[]> iterator = CombinatoricsUtils.combinationsIterator(assets.size(), 2);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final int[] combination = iterator.next();
        AssetDto firstAsset = assets.get(combination[0]);
        AssetDto otherAsset = assets.get(combination[1]);

        double weight = firstAsset.getWeight() / 100;
        double weightOther = otherAsset.getWeight() / 100;

        if (firstAsset.getStockReturns() != null && otherAsset != null) {
            List<Double> returns = firstAsset.getStockReturns().stream().limit(historyLength).collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<Double> returnsOther = otherAsset.getStockReturns().stream().limit(historyLength).collect(Collectors.toList());
            Covariance covariance = new Covariance();
            double assetsCovariance = covariance.
                    covariance(returns.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray(),
                            returnsOther.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray());
            portfolioVariance += 2 * weight * weightOther * assetsCovariance;
        }
    }
    return portfolioVariance;
}
```

Comment: This looks great. I will test it and confirm. Many thanks.